# h1 and p tag in same line, but keep h1 width

Tags: tags, line

Hy,
so i have this:

```
    #header
    {
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto 3% auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }

    #header p, h1
    {
    display: inline;
    }
    #header p
    {
    font-style: italic;
    }

    h1
    {   
    width: 40%;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    font-family: Franklin Gothic Medium;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 2.8em;
    margin-left: 2%;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px white;
    }
```

and the HTML

```
    <div id="header">
    <h1>Heading Blog Title</h1>
    <p>Site description Site description Site description Site description</p></div>
```

It looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hb52y.jpg

But I want to keep the width of the h1 too look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2nAF.jpg
Basically to center the

along with the h1 tag.
Picture 1 is where i used

```
    #header p, h1
    {
    display: inline;
    }
```

for both.
In the second picture the h1 tag is positioned as i want to, but the

screws it up. On the second pic I used display: inline-block; for the h1. And the p description isn't positioned in the center position, I can use margin pr padding but the rest of the description keeps going bellow the h1 tag as you can see on pic 2. 
I fixed this by relative positioning and margin the p tag, but it goes bellow or above the #header in higher or smaller resolutions because I used %.
Any trick to fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's a jsFiddle of the above...](http://jsfiddle.net/5WG5q/)

And [one solution](http://jsfiddle.net/5WG5q/1/)

- Get both h1 and p to display inline-block: 
  #header p, h1
  {
  display: inline-block;
  }
- Float both elements left, and give `#header p` a width of less than 60%
- Since floating removes elements from the natural document flow, you'll need to set a fixed height to the div container, so that it will still enclose the header.
- Add desired margins to get the `p` element sitting in the right place.

A note: this won't work at smaller screen sizes, since the `h1` text will stick out of it's container when it is wider than 40%. I suggest you give the h1 element a fixed width( or `min-width`) which you're happy with, and let `#header p` float to the left of it.

Comment: Well thanks, works fine. I set the height in px, doesn't look so bad on 1600px and above. I will use @media for 800 and less, that will adjust it on the right place.